# Design Patterns - Understanding Facade Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, uml, facade

I'm new to Design Patterns and am trying to learn how they typically look like. Right now I'm trying to understand the Facade Pattern. I feel like the Facade Pattern is a rather broad concept, and so I was wondering if my second diagram would be considered a part of the Facade Template.

I know a typical Facade Pattern basically looks like this(with the A-class being the facade):

[image]

But what if we have a more subtle diagram like this:

[image]

Would the A-class still be considered a Facade-class or does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to understand facade, I like to think of it as a kind of refactoring. Imagine both your diagrams *without* the facade classes. The clients would have to interact directly with all the classes that the facade manages. As such, they would be more complex, with more coupling.

A facade provides a simplified service to the clients (reducing coupling), hiding the complexity *behind* the facade.

My favorite example (in Java) is the `JOptionPane` class. It did not exist in the earliest versions of Java, and if you wanted to create a Yes/No question dialog, you (as a client) had to manage all the calls to Dialog, Button, etc. as well as handle the events, etc. All that complexity has been simplified into a static method inside the `JOptionPane` facade class. Here's a UML diagram from https://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/facade.html

[image]

Now to your question:

> Would the A-class still be considered a Facade-class or does it depend on the context?

If `A` is providing a simplified service to the clients that effectively uses the complex subsystem of `B`, `C`, `F` and `E`, without which the clients would have to interact with (be coupled to) all of them directly, then I'd say `A` is a facade.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there's an exception when working with the compound design pattern but normally especially in your case, the facade class would not change. Also, new dependencies can be added at any time. Hope this helps.

[Great Platform to learn Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Comment: Hmm, I thought Design Patterns were more like a guideline and not that strict, letting you make it specific depending on the context

Comment: It's true that depending on the context you can choose which design pattern will be applicable, but generally, they are just predefined templates. But doesn't mean that you cannot tailor the code structure to the needs of your project.

Comment: So would you say that my second diagram could be a "tailored" Facade Diagram, but is probably another pattern? Cause I can't seem to find any pattern that looks similar to my example... Maybe it isn't even a pattern?

Comment: The concept is still Facade, but In my humble opinion, one shouldn't force their code to align with a specific design pattern, especially if it complicates your code, there is really no use. And please don't get me wrong these are just my views and not facts someone else might beg to differ as design pattern subjects may be controversial at times, so I'm not a design pattern expert neither.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends of the context.

If you are new to Design Patterns, than [real life stories](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/) which describes a design patterns, can help you to speed up with learning/understand the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `A` class is as much a Façade in the second example as in the first, insofar as `A` is the sole entry point between the clients and the "subsystem". Whether the hidden subsystem is flat or hierarchical is immaterial to the clients or indeed, to the pattern.

Do note that the perceived utility of a Façade is somewhat proportional to the complexity it abstracts (hides) from clients. So the first example may be considered a more useful Façade as it hides four additional classes. The second example only hides two classes from the clients, assuming they would interact only with `B` and `C` in the absence of `A`.

Comment: The primary goal of facade is to hide complexity, another benefit is to manage dependency. So if we want that clients do not depend of B,C,E,F, even if B;C.E,F are simple, a facade could be a good idea. no?

Comment: Yes, reducing client dependencies by moving those dependencies to a Façade is part of what the pattern does to abstract (hide) complexity.