# Facade Pattern Need Example

Tags: design-patterns, facade

i'm actually searching for a real example of Facade pattern. Who have already used and where ?
Can u send me some link of application using this pattern.

I have understand how to use it. But i want know if he really used and by who

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has the JOptionPane class that has several methods for opening dialog boxes in Swing that simplify the use of the API.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47087638/1168342) for more details.